# Can you delete a project on bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

How can I delete a project on bitbucket.org?

Comment: Did you mean a repository? (In BitBucket, you can create multiple repositories associated with a single project)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easily: Go to your repository page (`bitbucket.org/you/repository_name`), click the "gear" icon on the bottom left, and on the left, under Repository Details, choose the item `Delete Repository`

Comment: I don't have any the gear icon on my repo

Comment: ok, mine is under Settings (bottom left) > delete

Comment: Glad you fixed the answer,just a pitty that people in this community are so nasty about it :(

Comment: If you are trying to delete a project (as appose to a repository) you should see a "Delete project" button on the top right corner of the screen when navigating to the Project "Settings" tab.